# Can you use Divine Smite while you are concentrating on a spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, paladin, spellcasting, concentration

I am playing as a multiclassed Hexblade warlock 3/paladin 2 in a D&D 5e campaign.

Can you use your paladin Divine Smite feature in melee while you are concentrating on a spell, such as *shadow blade* or *hex*?

While Divine Smite does consume spell slots, it is not a spell; therefore, is it reasonable to suggest that you can use Divine Smite while concentrating?

Comment: Do you have any reason for believing it might not work? Including that will let answers better address the issue you are having and/or clear up any underlying misunderstandings (those happen to the best of us).

Comment: Related question: [In what ways can a spellcaster's concentration be disrupted?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/74432/31589)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Yes

Only spells and effects that require concentration will cause you to stop your current spell concentration. This'll be mostly concentration spells, or magical items and class effects that have a phrasing along the lines 'as if you were concentrating on a spell'.

> As a bonus action, you cast command, without expending a spell slot, and you take on an appearance of unearthly beauty for 1 minute **or until your concentration ends (as if you were concentrating on a spell**).

Smite makes no mention of concentration. It simply uses a spell slot, and that's it. You might be getting confused with the various smite-named spells such as Searing Smite, which are actually concentration spells.