# Does being stunned interrupt concentration?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, conditions, concentration

Fairly simple question but I can't seem to find an answer to it. If a creature is concentrating on a spell and then becomes stunned, does their concentration on that spell end?

Comment: I'm not sure if we'd consider this a duplicate because it's the reverse, but pretty sure that this answers your question: [In what ways can a spellcaster's concentration be disrupted?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/74432)

Comment: Related: [What are the unlisted effects of the Incapacitated condition?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/172352/unlisted-effects-of-incapacitated-condition)

Comment: @NautArch Doesn't seem reverse to me; looks like an ideal canonical duplicate target for any question in the form of "Does x interrupt concentration?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In what ways can a spellcaster's concentration be disrupted?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/74432/in-what-ways-can-a-spellcasters-concentration-be-disrupted)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

#### Being Stunned ends concentration by inflicting the Incapacitated condition

One of the effects of the [Stunned](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Stunned) condition is this:

> - A stunned creature is incapacitated (see the condition), can't move, and can speak only falteringly.

Meanwhile, [the rules on Concentration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Concentration) state:

> [...] You lose concentration on a spell if you are incapacitated or if you die. [...]

From this, we can conclude that the Stunned condition ends concentration on spells.